# Im not able to create a selenium hub node with more than 2 sessions

Tags: selenium-grid, wdio

I was trying to create a docker compose with a chrome instance using selenium grid, but i want to create the node with more than 2 sessions, even if i change the SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS variable to 6 for example, i will alway got 2 sessions.

```
`version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
    shm_size: 10gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - VNC_NO_PASSWORD=1
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=3
      - SE_NODE_GRID_URL=http://selenium-hub:4444
    ports:
    - "5900-5910:5900-5910"

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:latest
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"`
```

i was trying to create a docker compose with selenium grid with more than 2 sessions, i want to create a selenium hub with more than 2